# Is there other form to restart udev in xenial, Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, upstart, udev

I have problems restarting `udev`, when I write

```
sudo restart udev
```

it tells me

```
restart: Impossible to connect with upstart: 
         Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: connection refused
```

What is the cause of this error message and how can I properly restart `udev`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

16.04 does not use upstart anymore, but systemd. The new command is:

> sudo systemctl restart udev.service